# spring-data @Query mapping result issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I've created a Repository that extends CrudRepository,
this repository has a method with an @Query notation:

Code:

```
@Query("select itemType, count(*) as count from Item where  User_id = :userId group by itemType")
List<Map<String, Long>> countItemsForUser(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

The issue I'm having is that this return a ArrayList of Object(s) and not a List of Map.
I've read somewhere that JPA can't return a Map so that's why I stuff the result in a List>.

I don't know what's the best way to work around this issue or to quickly access the result data. 
I've tried casting but that didn't work out either:

```
for(Object item: items) {
    Map<String,Long> castedItem = (HashMap<String,Long>)item;
}
```

Comment: item, which is of the type Object inside the loop doesn't have a method getString ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this example in official documentation of Hibernate.[Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying)

```
 for (Object item:items) {
   Object[] tuple = (Object[]) item;
    String itemType = (String)tuple[0];
    Long count = (Long) tuple[1];

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way is to use interface. To let Spring wire query alias 
 to the interface getter. Example can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions
also there is @SqlResultSetMapping. See:
[JPA- Joining two tables in non-entity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179180/jpa-joining-two-tables-in-non-entity-class/25184489#25184489)