# JPA- Joining two tables in non-entity class

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

I am a newbie ,tried to google but I am unable to solve my query.
Please help.

I am trying to map two entities : PersonA and Person in my POJO class PersonC

```
@Entity
class PersonA{
     String sample_field;
}

@Entity
class Person{
     String id;
     String name;

}
```

Above two are entities of jpa.

Now I want to merge them into one pojo class.

```
class PersonC
{
   Strind id;
   String address;
}
```

Tried below code but when I try to fetch Address/Foreign key field it does not work.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="PersonC", 
classes = {
   @ConstructorResult(targetClass = PersonC.class, 
    columns = {@ColumnResult(name="name")
              , @ColumnResult(name="address")
    )}
```

where should I define @SqlResultSetMapping ,for which class from the above?
      )
    })

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`@SqlResultSetMapping` can be placed at **any** entity class (don't annotate POJOs - it won't work). Mapping to POJO class with `@ConstructorResult` was added in version 2.1 of JPA. POJO used with the mapping has to have correct constructor.

> All columns corresponding to arguments of the intended constructor must be specified using the columns element of the ConstructorResult annotation in the same order as that of the argument list of the constructor.

Please consult following example with query usage and work out your case accordingly.

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id int id;  
    String street;
}


@SqlResultSetMapping(name="PersonDTOMapping",
    classes = {
     @ConstructorResult(targetClass = PersonDTO.class,
       columns = {@ColumnResult(name="name"), @ColumnResult(name="street")}
     )}
)
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id int id;
    String name;
    Address address;  
}  

public class PersonDTO {
    String name;
    String street;
    public PersonDTO(String name, String street) {
        this.name = name;
        this.street = street;
    }
}

// usage
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT p.name AS name, a.street AS street FROM Person p, Address a WHERE p.address_id=a.id",
    "PersonDTOMapping");
List<PersonDTO> result = query.getResultList();
```

Please note that aliases (`AS name` and `AS street`) has to match the names in `@ColumnResult`s.
The example was tested against Ecliselink 2.5.1.

Comment: So what then is the advantage of mapping it to a pojo?

Comment: can you give an example for JPA 2.0 using the @EntityResult and not the @ColumnResult?

Comment: Very similar to JPQL with the NEW keyword. 

So, the fun part is we're stuck in old JPA for now. Any thoughts about how you'd map this if you also joined the table PAIRS_OF_SHOES as a list?

Comment: As noted in the solution below this one you don't always have an entity class to add the annotations to, at least not the right one. Pretty common when calling stored procedures to map the results onto a DTO and you don't have an entity version of that DTO (for obvious reasons). Solution below solves that scenario.

Answer (score 10):

Just found a bit simpler solution using JPQL. 
I stole part of the example from @zbig's answer:

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id int id;  
    String street;
}

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id int id;
    String name;
    Address address;  
}  

public class PersonDTO {
    String name;
    String street;
    public PersonDTO(String name, String street) {
        this.name = name;
        this.street = street;
    }
}

List<PersonDTO> listOfPersons = em.createQuery("select new com.example.PersonDTO(p.name, a.street) " +
"from Person p, Address a " + 
"WHERE p.address.id=a.id", PersonDTO.class).getResultList();
```

The benefit of this solution is that you don't need to use the @SqlResultSetMapping annotation, which **must** be placed on **any** entity class, not the DTO class! And that's sometimes confusing because the entity class could only be partially related (when joining multiple tables for example).

More info [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: You are the Hero , i wish i can upvote this answer 100 times and also print your answer to my tshirt and wear always :)

Answer (score 7):

This post deals with the Hibernate.

The suggestion of putting the **@SqlResultSetMapping** and **@NamedNativeQuery** (or **@NamedQuery**) inside the **@Entity** class definition is not elegant and evidently does not follow the separation of concerns principle.

The more proper solution is the usage of the **@MappedSuperclass** annotation as the following:

**SingerExtended.java** (the class must be **abstract**):

```
package pl.music.model.singer.extended;

import javax.persistence.ColumnResult;
import javax.persistence.ConstructorResult;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;

@MappedSuperclass
@SqlResultSetMapping( // @formatter:off
    name = "SingerExtendedMapping",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = SingerExtendedDTO.class,
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "singer_id", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "first_name"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "last_name"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "count_albums", type = Long.class)
        }
    )
)
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
            name = "SingerExtendedAsc",
            query = "select"
                + " singer.singer_id,"
                + " singer.first_name,"
                + " singer.last_name,"
                + " (select count(*) from album where album.singer_id = singer.singer_id) as count_albums"
                + " from singer"
                + " group by singer.singer_id"
                + " order by last_name collate :collation asc, first_name collate :collation asc",
            resultSetMapping = "SingerExtendedMapping"
    )
}) // @formatter:on
public abstract class SingerExtended {
}
```

then DAO class **SingerExtendedDAO.java**:

```
package pl.music.model.singer.extended;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SingerExtendedDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private String collation;

    public List<SingerExtendedDTO> getAll(Integer page, Integer count) {
        TypedQuery<SingerExtendedDTO> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("SingerExtendedAsc", SingerExtendedDTO.class);
        query.setParameter("collation", collation);
        if ((count != null) && (count.intValue() > 0)) {
            query.setMaxResults(count.intValue());
            if ((page != null) && (page.intValue() >= 0)) {
                query.setFirstResult(count.intValue() * page.intValue());
            }
        }
        List<SingerExtendedDTO> singerExtendedDTOs = query.getResultList();
        return singerExtendedDTOs;
    }

}
```

and finally the DTO class **SingerExtendedDTO.java** (you must provide "full" constructor):

```
package pl.music.model.singer.extended;

public class SingerExtendedDTO {

    private Long singerId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Long countAlbums;

    // IMPORTANT: this constructor must be defined !!! 
    public SingerExtendedDTO(Long singerId, String firstName, String lastName, Long countAlbums) {
        this.singerId = singerId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.countAlbums = countAlbums;
    }
    ... getters & setters ...
}
```

If all this is put together the way presented above, we obtain a proper solution:

- everything is in one package,
- query declaration does not pollute any unconcerned entity,
- separation of concerns is preserved (seperated query+mapping, DAO and DTO).

Comment: This is a much better solution than the accepted one IMHO. In many cases when you're mapping stored proc results onto a DTO you don't have an entity to put these annotations on. This solves that problem handily.

Comment: I am getting `No query defined for that name [SingerExtendedAsc]`. Any ideas?

Comment: @krizajb @SqlResultSetMapping annotation should not be put on a POJO. Put it at (any) ```@Entity``` class (any entity will do, even one that is not related to the request)